# Piping user input into commands in C

Tags: c, shell, piping

So I have created a simple shell program which takes input from the user through cmd, and then creates a new task and executes the input as a command. For example:

> ls -l /home/user/Downloads | sort –u > listing.txt

But my program can only handle one piping. Can I somehow make it work with no limitations to pipings?? For example:

> ls -l /home/user/Downloads | sort –u | wc –l > count.txt

So far I have been unable to implement something like that.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    pid_t pid1,pid2,waitPid;
    int  status,n,j,k,in,out,pdes[2],current_out,current_in,returnValue;
    char *token;
    char array[256];
    char *temp[256];
    char *temp2[256];
    current_out=dup(1);
    current_in=dup(0);


    for(;;)
    {
        if(dup2(current_out,1) < 0)
        {
            printf("Error restoring output");
        }
        if(dup2(current_in, 0) < 0)
        {
            printf("Error restoring input");
        }
        int i=0;
        k=0;
        printf("mysh4>");
        int check = scanf("%d",&n);
        if(check == EOF)
        {
            printf("You now exit.\n");
            break; 
        }
        else
        {
            fgets(array,sizeof(array),stdin);
            array[strcspn(array,"\n")] = 0;
            token = strtok(array, " ");

            while(token != NULL)
            { 
                temp[i] = token;
                token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                i++;
                k++;
            }
            temp[i]= NULL;
            int p=0;
            int qq;

            for(i=0;i<k;i++)
            {
                if(strcmp(temp[i],"|") == 0)
                {
                    for(qq=i+1; qq<k; qq++)
                    {
                        temp2[p]=temp[qq];  
                        temp[qq-1] = NULL;  
                        printf("Temp2[%d] is: %s\n" , p , temp2[p]);    
                        printf("Temp1[%d] is: %s\n" , p , temp[p]); 
                        p++;
                    }
                    temp2[p]= NULL;
                }
            }

            returnValue=pipe(pdes);

            if (returnValue == -1) 
            {
                printf("ERROR: Pipe command failed.\n");
                return -1;
            }
            close(pdes[0]);
            close(pdes[1]);
            pid1 = fork();

            if (pid1 < 0) 
            {
                perror("ERROR: Fork failed.\n");
                return -1;
            }

            //child process
            if (pid1 == 0) 
            {
                close(pdes[0]);
                dup2(pdes[1],1);
                printf("Array:%s", array);
                execvp(array,temp);
                printf("Invalid Code\n");
                return -1;
            }

            pid2 = fork();
            if(pid2 < 0)
            {
                perror("Error: Fork2 failed.\n");
                return -1;
            }

            //child process 2
            if(pid2 == 0)
            {
                close(pdes[1]);
                dup2(pdes[0],0);
                for(j=0;j<k;j++)
                {
                    if(strcmp(temp[j],">") == 0)
                    {
                        out=j+1; 
                        printf("Output is %s\n", temp[out]);
                        temp[j] = temp[out];
                        pdes[1]=open(temp[out],
                         O_APPEND | O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
                        if(dup2(pdes[1],1) < 0)
                        {
                            printf("error in dup2");
                            return -1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                execvp(temp2[0],temp2);
                printf("Invalid Code 2\n");
                return -1;
            }

            //father process
            else 
            {
                //father waits child process to finish
                waitPid = wait(NULL);
                if (waitPid == -1) 
                {
                    perror("ERROR: Waitpid failed.\n");
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code. As it is at the moment, it's really hard to understand the structure of your code and that is quite important to the answer to this question.

Comment: In particular, you should replace all tab characters with a sequence of spaces.

Comment: Better now jeremyP?

Comment: Yes, much better.

Comment: Well now maybe you could give me an answer please?

Comment: What makes you think I have an answer?